# parallel working on video recording and phone call functionalities in iOS swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two methods like phone call function and camera video recording functions. These two functions working fine individually. But when I use these two functions at a time camera function not working. How can I call these two methods at a time for proper working in ios swift. I found the error is that audio enabling to both functions at a time. thats why it is crashing. May I disable the audio of video recording upto phone call completed?

```
func makeCall(phoneNumber: String) {
    let formattedNumber = phoneNumber.components(separatedBy:
        NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")

    let phoneUrl = "tel://\(formattedNumber)"
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: phoneUrl)!

    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler:
            nil)


    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)


    }
}
```

func videoMethodNew()

```
{

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType.video)


    guard AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) != nil else { return }

    for device in devices {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back{


            do{

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){

                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){

                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame


                    }

                    captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

                    captureSession.startRunning()

                    self.handleCaptureSession()

                }

            }
            catch{

                print("Error")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, what you trying to exactly do video calling?

Comment: @Purohit : I am making only normal call

Comment: what happened when you perform simultaneously like any error in debug area or else what happens in camera preview(it doesn't show)

Comment: This is the error: (Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11818 "Recording Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Recording Stopped, AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=true, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Stop any other actions using the recording device and try again., NSUnderlyingError=0x1047a70e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16414 "(null)"}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

As per your error -11818 it's happen means AVErrorSessionWasInterrupted like other apps interrupted your video decoding.For fix this problem you need to enable AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers.
For more Info use this link:- [enter link description here](https://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/interface_a_e_audio_controller.html)

Thanks